# How to get the total days in a month using count method in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get the present (P) student status. Then I want to count the total students present within a month. Unfortunately, my code doesn't work properly.

```php
$jan_count = Attendance::with(['level', 'student'])
    ->where(['level_id' => $id, 'status' => 'P'])
    ->whereMonth('days', '01')
    ->count()
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('student_id');
```

Comment: Show me your error what you get

Comment: can you explain more? like error

Comment: Call to a member function get() on integer

Comment: right you use count function thats return count get function only for array not count please remove get function you got counts

Comment: if you got result and count tell me i am helping you to this query

Comment: Call to a member function groupBy() on integer

Answer (score 0):

yes it will because its not a valid Query try the below Code

```
$jan_count = Attendance::with(['level','student'])
            ->where([ 
                        ['level_id' ,'=', $id],
                        ['status','=','P']
                    ])
            ->whereMonth('days', '01')
            ->get()
            ->groupBy('student_id');
```

If any issues kindly Comment Below

Comment: this is the "error Call to a member function get() on integer"

Comment: dont use get function. why you use get function in ?

Comment: Call to a member function groupBy() on integer

Comment: this will never work since you are using getting function after the count, which will fetch the total count of the provided query.

Answer (score 0):

Use only count function for get count if you get result assign one variable and get result

```
      $jan_count = Attendance::with(['level','student'])
        ->where([ 
                    ['level_id' ,'=', $id],
                    ['status','=','P']
                ])
        ->whereMonth('days', '01')
        ->groupBy('student_id')
        ->count();
```

Comment: Call to a member function groupBy() on integer